# Update only one field in nested document (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following MongoDB document:

```
key: "1",
_id: ObjectID(...);
    items: [
        {
            key: "1",
            value: 2
        },
        {
            key: "2",
            items: [
                {
                    key: "1",
                    value: 100
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to update only the second object in the base `items`. In this example `value: 100` in `items` of the second object in the base array `items`. How can I update only that field, e.g to 200, without having to update the entire document? Because I only have the document `_id`, but the items in it don't have a primary key. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should probably ship the items array into its own collection and store an array of  ObjectIds in the items array

Comment: @aosh5 : So do you need to update particularly second object or an object in an array that matches  a condition like for here : {value : 100} ??